# How to upgrade Django 1.3.1 to 1.3.7 on Ubuntu in Docker

Tags: django, django-1.3, versionupgrade

I have an old django project and I built it in docker for the development environment,
django 1.3.1 is installed. (Python version is 2.7 setting in docker-compose)

Is there any way to upgrade to django 1.3.7?
Thanks for advance.

I tried followings but don't work.

- apt-get upgrade django
- apt-get install python-pip and pip install [--upgrade] django==1.3.7

> Downloading/unpacking Django==1.3.7
> Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.3.7
> No distributions at all found for Django==1.3.7

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

...

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
        apache2 \
        libapache2-mod-wsgi \
        mysql-server \
        python-mysqldb \
        python-django
...
```